# Force language switch with URL parameter

Tags: javascript

Is there a way of forcing a language switch by URL parameter using javascript?

I want that when I go to this site 'wwww.google.com/en' he will be in English,
and when I went to 'wwww.google.com/it' he will be in Italian.

I have a button with setLanguage function that does this, but I want it to force it also when I get directly from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

That type of configuration of a single page is typically handled with a query string, not a separate path. Instead of this:

```
https://www.google.com/en
```

Do this:

```
https://www.google.com/?lang=en
```

The query string data are available in [searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams#Example):

```
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let lang = params.get('lang');
```

Answer (score -1):

with `window.location.pathname` you will get a USVString containing an initial '/' followed by the path of the URL, and to get the first item from the url you can do something like:

```js
const langURI = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]
```

You can get info about the USVString [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString)